# Don't Ask question when generate SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Sometimes I test an SSL website on my local machine. I was tired to use a self-signed certificate and add them to my KeyChain on Mac (Browser or other OS). Moreover, Chrome always complains about them. Moreover, this approach was a bit different from the one used in production.

I found this article very useful where you create once your own CA root certificate, add it once to your keychain and then you use the CA private key to sign thousands of SSL test certificate for my local websites.
https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

The tutorial works great but I would like to automate it. For the CA root certificate it was easy, I simply used the option `-subj` like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key /certs/myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -subj "/C=$CA_COUNTRY/ST=$CA_STATE/L=$CA_CITY/O=$CA_ORGANIZATION/CN=$CA_COMMON_NAME" -out /certs/myCA2.pem
```

where the environment variable (CA_COUNTRY, CA_STATE, CA_CITY, CA_ORGANIZATION, CA_COMMON_NAME) are read from an external file.

However, when I tried to replicate the same thing for the website certificate I wasn't able to get the same result. The command is this:

```
openssl x509 -req -in dev.deliciousbrains.com.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out dev.deliciousbrains.com.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile dev.deliciousbrains.com.ext
```

It seems that the `-subj` option doesn't work. Is there a way to pass the info above to this command and avoid interactive questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you show `openssl x509 -req -CA/-CAkey ...` does not ask any questions except the key password if there is one (which if you followed the instructions at the linked page there is). It is the **preceding** command to create the CSR `openssl req -new` that prompts for the subject name, and for that (like the command for creating the CA cert which is also `req` but with `-x509` -- note `-x509` is not the same as `x509`) you can use `-subj`. The statement on that page that "your answers don’t matter" isn't quite correct; it is true that when you use SubjectAlternativeName in the leaf cert, as that page advises/directs, the value of Subject is ignored for (at least) HTTPS server identification, but it must (still) be *different* from the name used for the CA to allow certificate validation to work. *Standards* allow the Subject name in a leaf cert to be empty when SAN is used (and empty is always different from nonempty and a nonempty name is required in the CA cert) but OpenSSL doesn't handle that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot. Do you know if there is a way in the last command (the one that creates the leaf certificate) there is a way to pass the CA private key pass phrases as an ENVIRONMENT variable so that the script is not interactive at all?

Comment: See the man page under `-passin` which points/links you to the 'toplevel' man page https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options